# Bitbucket Pipelines Node js with mongo connection

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I am using this as a `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`:

```
image: spittet/node-mongodb

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - npm install
          - service mongod start
          - npm test
```

and in the tests I have the connection to mongo db.
like this:

```
const localhost = process.env.HOSTNAME || "localhost";
mongoose.connect('mongodb://'+localhost+'/testslab');
```

But this doesn't work. How should I connect to bitbucket pipelines mongo db? What host should I use?

Comment: Maybe mongod isn't ready when the tests have started? Have you checked the logs to see it really started?